# How does the Lorentz force on a wire create macroscopic movement?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electrons, conductors

In a a current carrying wire exposed to a magnetic field, the electrons will experience a force and hence, a net displacement from. However it is not clear to me how this causes the wire to bend/move in relation to this.
What is the structural mechanism that causes the wire to move from the current?

Comment: The electrons are part of the wire. If the electrons have a force exerted on them, so does the wire they reside in.

Comment: Why do we think there is such a thing as the Lorentz force? The answer is that Ampère and others measured the force between current carrying wires. The Lorentz force is a mathematical story we tell to capture those observations.

Comment: @JohnDoty Lorentz force is not merely a mathematical story, it is also rooted in experiments with cathode rays in cathode ray tubes in static external electric and magnetic field.

Comment: @JánLalinský Actually, it worked the other way around. The Lorentz force deflecting cathode rays was understood on the basis of Ampère's Force Law applied to particles rather than wires, and some of the properties of the electron were inferred this way.

Comment: @JohnDoty yes that is the historical progression, but nevertheless the experiments with cathode rays in vacuo validate the Lorentz force formula in a different, better way than macroscopic magnetic forces on a current-carrying wire do.

Comment: @JánLalinský I don't know that it's better. How do you measure the force on an electron? Look at its acceleration? Well you need to know q/m. How do you measure that?

Measuring force Ampère's way is much more direct.

Comment: @JohnDoty it is better in that it is more direct, because effect of force on motion of electrons is observed, instead of force on macroscopic conductor. Quantity $q/m$ need not be known to verify the basic properties of the Lorentz force: that there is electric force and magnetic force perpendicular and proportional to velocity, and ratio of their magnitudes. One can then determine $q/m$ quantity assuming the verified form of the Lorentz force.

Comment: @JánLalinský But that's not better. It's more abstract, less physical. The roots of physics are macroscopic. Physics isn't something that only happens in labs full of exotic equipment: it happens in the world all around us.

Comment: @JohnDoty when we talk about experimental basis of the Lorentz force, I don't think force on electron beam is any less interesting or important than force on a wire. Let's agree to disagree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the Lorentz force acts to move electrons toward one side of the wire. Conduction electrons will respond by accumulating on that side of the wire. However, they cannot simply keep going and exit the wire, as they are bound to the lattice of the material making up the wire and it would take a great deal of energy to extract them from the wire (see [work function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function)).

The electromagnetic forces binding the conduction electrons to the wire prevent them from moving out of the wire. In return, the reaction force that the electrons exert on the wire accelerates the wire in the direction of the Lorentz force on the conduction electrons.